# Bypassing a Singularity

Tags: differential-equations

I am having trouble trying to solve an ODE that has a singularity when the function `M[x]=1`.  Basically the denominator has `1-M[x]^2` in the ODE, so when `M[x]=1` I end up with `1/0`.  Is there a way I can bypass the `M[x]=1` part of the solution or replace it with a linear interpolation say between 0.95 and 1.05?  To help clarify, I am modeling the Mach number `M[x]` in a ram/scram jet with the Mach number as a function of length x.  When the Mach number is 1.0 the equation becomes singular.  I have tried using a when event, but I was not successful with that method so I am hopeful there may be another solution.  Here is the code I am using.

```
γ = 1.25
a[x] = athroat*(ar - ((ar - 1)/20)*x)
Derivative[1][a][x] = D[a[x], x]
Subscript[t, t][0] = 200
Subscript[t, t][x] = 140*x + Subscript[t, t][0]
Subscript[f, Subscript[T, 0]] = 
  (m[x]*(1 + 0.125*m[x]^2)*(1 + 1.25*m[x]^2))/(2*(1 - m[x]^2))
Subscript[Eqn, Heat] = Derivative[1][m][x] == 
   Subscript[f, Subscript[T, 0]]*(140/Subscript[t, t][x])
s = NDSolve[{Subscript[Eqn, Heat], m[0] == 0.15}, m, {x, 0, 20}]
Plot[Evaluate[m[x] /. s], {x, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "M[X]"}]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the ODE? Does it help to clear denominators before solving?

Comment: In general you should stop and analyse when there is a singularity. Bypassing it is not a good option! Maybe you can change the initial conditions and simulate for lesser time such that the system does not hit singularity. Also, consider changing the parameters of the system (link lengths of a mechanism) so that singularity is not encountered. Bypassing singularity is not the right way!